# Doctrine: How to write this json query using PHP and doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I got a simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM club
WHERE club = 34558
AND JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.activities.*'), '7','$') IS true;
```

How can I write this query using PHP and doctrine. Also '7' here is optional, so probably passable param, let's call it `:desired`